# Разбитной - происхождение слова

Tags: этимология

Разбитным называют человека веселого, компанейского, но при этом невоспитанного и развязного. Например: «Был человек разбитной, обязательный, склонный к разуму» (Н. Некрасов).
И вот мне интересно, почему подобного человека так называют? Ясно же, что это от слова "разбиться", но почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

РАЗБИТНОЙ, Разг. Бойкий, живой и несколько развязный.

Синонимы: Бойкий, бодрый, живой, лихой, проворный, расторопный, резвый.

Из словаря Крылова:

Это прилагательное, имеющее значение "расторопный, сообразительный", образовано от глагола разбить (в диалектах еще употребляющегося в значении "победить"), образованного приставочным способом от бить.

КОММЕНТАРИЙ

Можно предположить, что дополнительное значение  "несколько развязный" обусловлено сходством структуры этих слов: разбить - разбитной, развязать - развязный.В результате получается; разбитной - это  "развязный победитель".

РАЗВЯЗНЫЙ - подчёркнуто свободный, излишне непринуждённый, бесцеремонный в общении, поведении.

Answer (score 2):

"*Разбитны'й* - расторопный, проворный, ловкий" (Словарь 1847).
Одно из значений глагола *разбить* - разметить, организовать, поставить (лагерь, шатер, палатку, место под застройку и др.)
Умелый, ловкий организатор всякого рода хлопотливых дел - *разбитной парень*, мастер на все руки. Разбитной - имеющий ко всему и каждому свой подход, вообще человек *свойский* в любой компании.